# Last item visited become first item of the list

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

This the list I return from the Items collection

```
Template.itemsList.helpers({
    items: function () {
        return Items.find({});
    }
});
```

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- ...

If I visit the *Item 3* route `/items/3` when I come back to the `/items` route, the list is

- Item 3
- Item 1
- Item 2
- ...

Same thing if click on the *Item 2* and so on.

Yes, if I order the collection with `Items.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}})` and then I visit the `/items` route, the list is displayed correctly.

Why I notice this - *to me very strange* - behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior might seem strange at first, but actually it is not. If you don't explicitly specify the sort order, the result is returned in arbitrary order which may change over time.

It depends on the implementation of the backing database what the order will be. It can be in the order documents are added to the database. Or maybe in the order of when the documents where last updated or fetched. This is what you seem to be experiencing. It is a database implementation detail and you should **never** rely on this behavior.

If the order is important to you, always explicitly specify it!

Meteor uses [Minimongo](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/minimongo) to mimic the mongo api in the browser. I don't know much about its implementation, but it could very well use a list or stack of collection documents of which the order is influenced by document access. But this last bit is just guessing on my part...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it is caused also when the document it is fetched: good to know. Thanks.

Comment: The point is: you don't know, and you shouldn't rely on this behavior nor assume any behavior when the order is unspecified.